# Change URL Hyperlink color but not other hyperref colors

Tags: hyperref, links

Building on the question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255367/bibliography-hyperlink-to-show-up-blue/255383#255383/here), I just wanted the web hyperlink to be blue but the other hyperlinks to remain the color it was.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap1.bib}
 @online{pll_wikipedia,
    url={http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    %note = {Last visited on <insert date here>},
    title = {Phase-Locked Loop},
    %month = aug,
    %year = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% line breaks in URLs at "-"
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= blue,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={`Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{chap1.bib}
 \defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{same}}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is just some text to show the text lines before the align environment \cite{pll_wikipedia}.

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  T1 & - & This is an explanation of equaion 1 \\
  T2 & - & This is the explanation of another equ \\
  T2T3 & - & $\dfrac{Test}{Test2}$ \\
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\section*{Bibliography}
\subsection*{Online}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=online,prefixnumbers={O}]

\end{document}
```

If I run this code, my other hyperlinks (like `\cite`, `\label`,  `\tableofcontents` colors get affected.  Is there a way to locally change just the web url color with this setup?

Comment: you need `colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black`

Comment: You hypersetup twice, one with `colorlinks`, once without. Get rid of the one that doesn't contain colorlinks. Btw, this reference should be of type ` @online\  rather than `@misc`, and `howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop}},` should be replaced with the simpler `url={http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop},`.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for your input with the `@online`, however, when I use `@online`, and I place a period after the link: `url={http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop.},`, there is a problem with the hyperlink.  If I however use the `@misc` with `howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop}.}`, the link works fine.  The period is not part of the actual link in this latter case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated: Edit** You need to add `colorlinks=true` or `colorlinks`
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{hidelinks,
backref=true,
pagebackref=true,
hyperindex=true,
breaklinks=true,
colorlinks=true,%linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=false,
pdftitle={Title},
pdfauthor={Author}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
bla bla 

\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop}
\section{first}\label{mm} bla bla
\section{last} bla bla \ref{mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use the command `\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= blue,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}`, my tableofcontents, figure numbers, and `\cite` all also change colors.  I just want the url in the bib to be blue without affecting the rest of my document.  I am using the Legrand Orange book template.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the command from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/how-to-style-text-in-hyperref-url): `\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{red}\rmfamily\itshape}` and was able to just change the url font and color.

Comment: This command does not allow the link to automatically break between multiple lines. So for me, using in my preamble `\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}` worked better.